# Microsoft Teams steals audio

Tags: audio, bluetooth, volume-mixer, microsoft-teams

I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones connected to my laptop running Windows 10. Microsoft Teams aggressively steals the audio focus, sometimes refusing to give it back. What can I do to remedy this?

Whenever Teams pops up a notification (someone says something, a meeting starts), my headphones mute for a second. When I join a meeting, all other sounds are muted. That is often useful, but I'm unable to adjust the audio. Teams doesn't show up in the volume mixer. I have to use the volume buttons on my headphones instead.
I've noticed that this doesn't happen when using the laptop's speakers and mic.

Sometimes when a meeting ends, other sounds remain muted. I have to switch my headphones off and on again to solve this.

Are there any settings I can change to make Teams behave itself?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find working any solution I came across on Internet, but mine own solution working for me was, paradoxically to disable every single sound device in the sound settings (not device manager), that there left not even one sound device=empty list, and it worked.

Maybe because elsewhere was mentioned that the ms teams creates a copy of the device, while it is not displayed in the sound devices, only in volume mixer.
Quite highly voted suggestion too "to go back to the previous audio device", my problem was I had no other second previous audio device left to go back to - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/teams-mutes-all-sound/aaeb5e6e-142a-4367-bc7f-5ab387324706.